# Consejos para diseñar app de escritorio en java para un consultorio médico

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando una app de escritorio en java para la administración de un consultorio médico. Me gustarÍa que me dieran recomendaciones para diseñarlo. Por ejemplo: uso el patrón de diseño mvc?, lo desarrollo en módulos ?, cómo se desarrolla software hoy en día ? Muchas gracias y espero haber sido claro con mi pregunta.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Te recomiendo que sigas un patron de diseño. Ayuda a que tu interfaz de usuario sea mas intuitiva (al estar basada en patrones el usuario infiere que hacer en lugar de probar diferentes alternativas al no tener uno) y te ayuda a trabajar de forma mas organizada. MVC es el mas usado así que por que no usarlo tu también?

PD: recuerda que el sitio es para preguntas mas técnicas y no para discusiones o temas de opinion así que trata de formular la pregunta de una forma distinta la próxima vez ;)